# Proof that a set is open.

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $(\Lambda_i)_{i\in I}$ a collection of linear operators from $X$ (Banach space) to $Y$ (Normed space).

Let $\alpha : X \rightarrow [0,\infty]$ be the function $\alpha(x):=\sup_{i \in I} \|\Lambda_ix\|$.

Let $A_n:=\{x \in X : \alpha(x)>n\}$

I want to prove in a direct way that this set is open for every $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

So I want to find an $r_{x_0}$ such that if $x_0 \in A_n$ then $\sup_{i \in I}\|\Lambda x\|>n$ for each $x$ in the open ball $B_{r_{x_0}}:=\{x\in X: \|x-x_0\|<r_{x_0}\}$ .

But I'm blocked.
 Can you give me a little help? Thank you!

Comment: Find an $i$ so that $\lVert \Lambda_i x_0\rVert > n$. Pick an $r_{x_0}$ based on that.

Comment: I tried to take $x$ such that $\|x-x_0\|<\frac{1}{\|\Lambda_k x_0\|n}$ ($k$ being the index that you suggested) but I'm unable to arrive anywhere trying to fill the chain of unequalities $\sup_i \|\Lambda_i x\| > ... > n$. Another clue please?

Comment: Pick $r_{x_0}$ so that $\lVert x-x_0\rVert < r_{x_0} \implies \lVert \Lambda_k x\rVert > n$. (For that specific $k$ you picked with $\lVert \Lambda_k x_0\rVert > n$.)

Comment: Let $k$ be an index such that $\|\Lambda_k x \|> n$. If I choose $\|x-x_0\|< 1/\|\Lambda_k\|$ then I have: $\sup_i \|\Lambda_i x\| \geq \|\Lambda_k x\|\geq \|\Lambda(x_0)\|-\|\Lambda(x-x_0)\|>n-\|\Lambda_k\|\|x-x_0\|>n-1$... but I need "> n".

Comment: Indeed. So you don't choose $1$ as the numerator, but something depending on $\Lambda_k x_0$. You want $$\lVert \Lambda_k x\rVert \geqslant \lVert \Lambda_k x_0\rVert - \lVert \Lambda_k\rVert\,\lVert x-x_0\rVert = n + (\lVert \Lambda_k x_0\rVert - n) - \lVert \Lambda_k\rVert\,\lVert x-x_0\rVert > n.$$

Comment: Oh that's right: I have to choose $x$ such that $\|x-x_0\|<\frac{\|\Lambda_k x_0\|-n}{\|\Lambda_k\|}$. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Note however that $$A_n = \bigcup_{i\in I} \{ x : \lVert \Lambda_ix\rVert > n\}$$ is a simpler way to see that $A_n$ is open: a union of open sets.